# Is there a way to boot 2 or more linux operating systems at once?

Tags: boot

Is there a way to boot multiple os at once?

E.g. have my discord bots on diffrent operating systems that are running at the same time?

EDIT: I already know unRAID, but i want something free and/or open source

Comment: You can have two OS running at the same time if one of them is a virtual machine. VBox or such.

Comment: i know, but i want to have max performance. Vir. machines dont give you that

Comment: Why do you need different OS to run at the same time at all? Are all the OS linux distributions?

Comment: @Burgerl X We have a tradition here of trying to get to the heart of the matter, for we see a lot of "XY" questions https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem where folks _think_ they know the best/only solution to a problem, and get fixated on that solution instead of explaining the problem and letting the Collective Wisdom (hah!) here find the best solution to the problem. That's why folks ask questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simultaneous operating systems require virtualization. No other solution available.

Comment: but then whats the best os to run virtualisation on to max performance?

Comment: Different issue requires asking that in a new question as per house rules regarding 'reasonable scope'. https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask  Please consider that some virtualization systems install on bare metal with no underlying OS. Also, 'best' should be avoided because it's subjective; instead, use objective terms such as 'tested as highest performing' or 'measured as most stable' or whatever criteria you wish to consider most important. You may find this list useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtualization_software

Comment: Max performance for *what*? In general, virtualization has a overhead, but increased average utilization may make it worth the overhead.

Comment: I think I'd go with Debian in that case for performance

Comment: @sh4dowb Have you seen a study which shows Debian is a superior platform to host VMs? If so, what's the URL? That's what the OP was asking for.

Comment: @K7AAY I meant the guest host as Debian, because it's lightweight and good enough, I guess? It's just my opinion