# Is it possible to run HDD installed windows 7 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: dual-boot

I have a dual-boot PC. Although I mostly use Ubuntu 20.04, sometimes I have to switch to Windows 7 which is installed on the same HDD. But to do that, as you know I have to reboot the PC and select windows 7 to boot. And it is boring to do that every time I need to.

So I would like to ask you if it is possible to run the Windows on Linux desktop. I know a virtual machine is an option but to use that I think I should install a fresh Windows. I want to know if I can use my installed and ready windows 7 as a virtual machine or something?

Comment: Not and answer: Yes and no, it depends. If possible/doable it's very complex to set up, may not work acceptably and may corrupt Windows leaving it unbootable. Not really recommend for regular users. Furthermore, you shouldn't be using Windows 7 because EoL, unsupported, unpatched and really dangerous to use online.  This may or may not be relevant for BIOS/Legacy installations like the one you probably have: https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-virtual-machine-of-windows-os/

Comment: It is possible to get/upgrade to Win 10 for free, even now(google free win 10) legally.  To use software you would need to use virtual machine, if not wanting to reboot.  Depending on the software, Wine might help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to boot 2 or more linux operating systems at once?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174820/is-there-a-way-to-boot-2-or-more-linux-operating-systems-at-once)

Answer (score 0):

## Virtual Machine

You can setup a VM (Virtual Machine) in Linux to run Windows or a VM in Windows to run Linux. This would alleviate the dual-booting hassle.

Below is a [closed post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195536/comparison-between-linux-host-windows-guest-vs-windows-host-linux-guest-vs-2-de) from Unix and Linux Stack Exchange that gives a good overview:

---

### Comparison between: Linux host Windows guest vs Windows host Linux guest vs 2 dedicated machines w/ KVM switch [closed]

Virtualization is usually a better choice, rather than "two desktops". But that may not always be true.

First, you must determine if what you want to do can be virtualized. Office products and other such low load things should be just fine. High CPU tasks usually work fine. High ram tasks are usually okay but could be a problem if you don't have the overhead to run both OSes and the ram chewing task at the same time. Tasks that require specific hardware *may* work, but typically do not, or require complicated configurations. If you can virtualize then it's a question of which way.

I am a fan of Linux hosts and Windows guests. However, it may not be the right way. Generally speaking, Linux is better at being the virtualization host if you're doing *normal* office stuff. If your trying to get some super special hardware running in the VM, particularly if it needs to interface with some hardware (as mentioned), Windows may be the better host. I also think Windows hosts have a tiny bit better support for GPU emulation for 3D rendering, but I have never seen it make a difference.

So what you're really left with is what is the best tool for the job? Do you spend more "time" in Windows or Linux? That one should be the host, the other the guest. The only thing that should override that (time-based preference) is special hardware needs.

Some quick notes on the methods:

1. Probably the right choice based on your question. Can share clipboard, and it is usually easier to access Linux Host resources in a windows guest than the other way around. There is no downside (especially if you have virtualization enabled hardware)
2. Windows is not as stable as Linux in most cases, and if your Host OS crashes you lose both the host and all running guests. That said, Linux is very "used to" begin virtualized, and probably runs better as a guest than Windows does. However, that is not likely to matter for office work. (For example, Windows guest OSes seem to always have networking issues under high load conditions)
3. Probably the worst way to go these days based on your question. That said, it is the tried and true method. In addition, it is the only choice if you need hardware-level access to something you can not get working on a guest OS.

Answer (score -2):

You can access every file you have in your Windows installation, just need to mount the partition.

But, I don't believe is possible to **run** your current Windows system

You'll need to setup a new Windows in a virtual machine

Comment: Thank you.Actually i am not trying to reach my files.I have a few softwares only run on windows 7.I need to use them.So i should install a new windows i think.

Comment: Júnior, it is possible - https://www.maketecheasier.com/create-virtual-machine-of-windows-os/ - but not recommended.